# Dynamically creating form in JQuery and posting it with JSON

Tags: jquery, json, xslt

I am trying to dynamically create a campaignmonitor newsletter subscription inside my XSLT code.

```
<script type="text/javascript"><xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[

    $(function() {
        $('#submit').click(function() {
             if ($('#nlapproved').attr('checked')) {
                newsletter();
            }
        });

        function newsletter()
        {
            $form = $('<form action="http://mydomain.createsend.com/t/j/s/jtes/" method="post" id="subForm" />');
            $form.append('<input type="hidden" name="cm-name" id="hidName" />');
            $form.append('<input type="hidden" name="cm-jtes-jtes" id="hidEmail" />');
            $form.append('<input type="hidden" name="cm-fo-pikty" id="hidPrivateBusiness" />');

            $form
                .find("#hidName")
                .val(']]></xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="$context//checkoutinformation/info[key='name']/value" disable-output-escaping="yes"/><xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[');

            $form
                .find("#hidEmail")
                .val(']]></xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="$context//checkoutinformation/info[key='email']/value" disable-output-escaping="yes"/><xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[');

            $form
                .find("#hidPrivateBusiness")
                .val(']]></xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="$acctype"/><xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[');

            $.getJSON(
                $($form).get(0).action + "?callback=?",
                $($form).serialize(),
                function (data) {
                    if (data.Status === 400) {
                        alert("Error: " + data.Message);
                    } else { 
                        // 200
                        alert("Success: " + data.Message);
                    }
                }
            );
        }
    });
]]></xsl:text></script>
```

Everything works fine till i call `getJSON` method. After that nothing works. I cant find any JavaScript errors in my Mozilla Error console. And i have checked whether the form is created correctly `alert($('<div>').append(($form).clone()).html());` displays correct result.

```
<form action="http://mydomain.createsend.com/t/j/s/jtes/" method="post" id="subForm"><input value="552" name="cm-name" id="hidName" type="hidden"><input value="aks@mydomain.com" name="cm-jtes-jtes" id="hidEmail" type="hidden"><input value="268278" name="cm-fo-pikty" id="hidPrivateBusiness" type="hidden"></form>
```

Comment: so, the idea is to **create** and **submit** it, without any user intervention, is that it? if yes, why not using their [fantastic API](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/api/)? I use it every day...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the [jQuery API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/), re the callback function:

> success(data, textStatus, jqXHR) A callback function that is executed if the request succeeds.

Maybe adding a fail listener will help:

```
$.getJSON(
    $($form).get(0).action + "?callback=?",
    $($form).serialize(),
    function (data) {
        if (data.Status === 400) {
            alert("Error: " + data.Message);
        } else { 
            // 200
            alert("Success: " + data.Message);
        }
    }
).error(function(data) {
    alert('have error http: ' + data);
}).complete(function(data){
    alert('have complete: ' + data);
});
```

Update:

May also have something to do with a JSON error. From the [API doc](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/):

> Important: As of jQuery 1.4, if the JSON file contains a syntax error, the request will usually fail silently.

Switching to a `$.get(...)` call might test this theory.

Comment: @AthulkSurendran Hm, might have something to do with a JSON error. From the [API doc](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/): "Important: As of jQuery 1.4, if the JSON file contains a syntax error, the request will usually fail silently."